# JetBrains Aqua - Multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jetbrains-ide, web-api-testing

I want to test one HTTP endpoint with thousands of different request bodies which I can generate in Excel. I also want to compare results (or results fields) to expected results which I will have in that Excel file too. Can I do this in JetBrains Aqua or will I need another tool?

I've tried googling and searching for some tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought for this scenario would now be tests with Postman. Or with Cypress.